# 'The Needler' human alien war against the Soetti (sweaty)

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, warfare

This is a story from an anthology, I cannot recall the author but I may have first read it in the 1960's or 1970's.
The title actually refers to the protaganists superior, who charges him with solving the technical problem of a strange new weapon that enemy aliens are using against us.

The aliens are called the Soetti, aka the Sweaties.
From what I recall of the illustratons, the ships were spherical or tear drop shapped, the aliens were humanoid with thick tendrils instead of hair.

The weapon causes all humans on board a ship to become catatonic.  It is later discovered that it was designed to kill. The solution to the problem is that a harmonic is set up between human weapons and the new alien weapon when both are fired during a battle.
It is this harmonic that has the effect attributed to the new alien weapon.

I have performed many searches on these terms but nothing relevent has been found. I hope someone here can help identify this story.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The Soetti are the alien antagonists in Keith Laumer's Retief story "[Courier](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?61850)" (available to read free on the [publisher's website](https://www.baen.com/Chapters/0671698796/0671698796___2.htm)). The humans call them "sweaties" and there are weapons called "needlers" but not many other details match.

You may be conflating two stories, because there is a Randall Garrett story called "[Needler](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55711)" that does involve a weapon that causes catatonia due to a "loop feedback pattern".  You can read this story at the  [Luminist Archive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xyAyYhZP5yr3pvGbDUsB0AJ7RJYSHakm/view). The ship illustrations indeed show spherical craft. The aliens in this story are called the Enlissa.

[image: illustration: futuristic car races toward docked round spacecraft]

Comment: Well caught, I had indeed conflated the two stories! The correct one is "Needler" by Randal Garrett. I have read a lot of the Retief stories and first read "Courier" as "The Frozen Planet". Thanks for reminding me of this, it is still in my library.